# Is the UDP checksum allowed to be calculated from a truncated payload?

Tags: c, sockets, networking, udp, protocols

UDP sockets only accept incoming datagrams if they have the right checksum. But I've heard that sometimes UDP packets are truncated because of the *Maximum Transmission Unit* (MTU).

**(1)** How are datagrams handled that are truncated purposely? Is it allowed that the checksum is calculated over a truncated payload? Or is it required that the checksum is always calculated over the whole data the application intended to send in one datagram?

**(2)** Also, is it allowed that a datagram is fragmented and then de-fragmented in another or incomplete order? Would that corrupt the checksum?

**The main question is:** Is it guaranteed that when a UDP datagram is received with the right checksum and passed to the application, that the payload is exactly the data that the sender application passed to the OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've heard that sometimes UDP packets are truncated because of the Maximum Transmission Unit (MTU).

You misheard. They can be *fragmented* for that reason.

> (1) How are datagrams handled that are truncated purposely?

They aren't truncated, they are fragmented. If all the fragments arrive, the datagram can be reconstituted and its checksum verified. Otherwise nothing happens.

> Is it allowed that the checksum is calculated over a truncated payload?

Impossible, see above.

> Or is it required that the checksum is always calculated over the whole data the application intended to send in one datagram?

Yes.

> (2) Also, is it allowed that a datagram is fragmented and then de-fragmented in another or incomplete order?

No.

> Would that corrupt the checksum?

It wouldn't even happen.

> The main question is: Is it guaranteed that when a UDP datagram is received with the right checksum and passed to the application, that the payload is exactly the data that the sender application passed to the OS?

Yes.

Comment: Thank you so much :) Finally I got the concept of UDP.

Comment: @MinecraftShamrock however, it is not guaranteed that UDP packets are received at all, hence their use is for applications where that does not matter.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes. I had already known that. But I wasn't sure _how_ unreliable UDP was.

Comment: As @EJP wrote, if the checksum is correct, the packet is good - except for those rare events where ... to stretch the point, consider an EAN barcode, the last digit is a checksum that has a one in eleven (includes X) chance of being falsely correct.